# Did pip3 install psycopg2, but can't import into visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio, psycopg2

I was able to run pip3 install psycopg2, and it returns saying its installed.
I was also able to run pip install psycopg2-binary and it says its installed.
Yet when I try to run import psycopg2 in my .py files on visual studio code it says for module found named psycopg2. Furthermore, when I run python in terminal and run import psycopg2 it says there is no module found by that name. I am using apple m1 chip so im not quite sure whether I installed it incorrectly or if psycopg2 is still unavailable on mac m1. Any help would be most appreciated.